# Mac OSX 10.8 git commands don't work after trying to use git-credential-osxkeychain

Tags: macos, git

Following setup instructions in https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git to prevent credential entry for each git command, git stopped responding. Every git command "locks up" the terminal until I press enter and I regain terminal control, but git doesn't do anything. I tried reverting to defaults settings without luck.